# Values stored using union display incorrectly

Tags: c, unions

I have this code. The problem is, that when I'm trying to display the value stored using union, it displays just some random numbers. Can you help me, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef union s_datatype {
    int t_int;
    char* t_char;
    double t_double;
    bool t_bool;
} t_datatype;

typedef struct s_node {
    char*name;
    int type;
    t_datatype value;
    struct s_node*left;
    struct s_node*right;
} t_node;

t_node*init_node (char*name, int type, t_datatype value) {
    t_node*root = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
    if (root == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    root->name = name;
    root->type = type;
    root->value = value;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}

void init_root (t_node*(*root)) {
    *root = NULL;
}

void insert_node (t_node*(*root), t_node*node) {
    if ((*root) == NULL) {
        (*root) = node;
    } else {
        if (strcmp((*root)->name, node->name) > 0) {
            insert_node(&((*root)->left), node);
        } else if (strcmp((*root)->name, node->name) < 0) {
            insert_node(&((*root)->right), node);
        } else if (strcmp((*root)->name, node->name) == 0) {
            (*root) = node;
        }
    }
}

void free_table (t_node*node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        free_table(node->left);
        free_table(node->right);
        free (node);
        node = NULL;
    }
}

void print_tree2(t_node*root, char* sufix, char fromdir) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        char* suf2 = (char*) malloc(strlen(sufix) + 4);
        strcpy(suf2, sufix);
        if (fromdir == 'L') {
            suf2 = strcat(suf2, "  |");
            printf("%s\n", suf2);
        } else {
            suf2 = strcat(suf2, "   ");
        }
        print_tree2(root->right, suf2, 'R');
        printf("%s  +-[%s,%d,%d]\n", sufix, root->name, root->value.t_int);
        strcpy(suf2, sufix);
        if (fromdir == 'R') {
            suf2 = strcat(suf2, "  |");
        } else {
            suf2 = strcat(suf2, "   ");
        }
        print_tree2(root->left, suf2, 'L');
        if (fromdir == 'R') {
            printf("%s\n", suf2);
        }
        free(suf2);
    }
}

void print_tree(t_node*root)
{
  printf("Binary tree structure:\n");
  printf("\n");
  if (root != NULL)
     print_tree2(root, "", 'X');
  else
     printf("Tree is empty\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("=================================================\n");
}

int main (void) {

    t_node*root;
    init_root(&root);
    t_datatype tt;

    tt.t_int = 0;
    t_node*node = init_node("zero", 0, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 1;
    node = init_node("first", 1, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 2;
    node = init_node("second", 2, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 3;
    node = init_node("third", 3, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 4;
    node = init_node("fourth", 4, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 5;
    node = init_node("fifth", 5, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 6;
    node = init_node("sixth", 6, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 7;
    node = init_node("seventh", 7, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 8;
    node = init_node("eighth", 8, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 9;
    node = init_node("ninth", 9, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    tt.t_int = 10;
    node = init_node("tenth", 10, tt);
    insert_node(&root, node);

    print_tree(root);
    free_table(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a warning - Format expects a matching int argument. (The line, where I'm displaying the values in the `print_tree2`)

The output:

```
Binary tree structure:

  +-[zero,0,1]
     |
     |     +-[third,3,10]
     |     |  |
     |     |  |  +-[tenth,10,16]
     |     |  |  |
     |     |  +-[sixth,6,18]
     |     |     |
     |     |     +-[seventh,7,18]
     |     |
     |  +-[second,2,12]
     |  |  |
     |  |  |  +-[ninth,9,13]
     |  |  |  |
     |  |  +-[fourth,4,15]
     |  |
     +-[first,1,9]
        |
        +-[fifth,5,9]
           |
           +-[eighth,8,12]

=================================================
```

Comment: Just LOL ... Forgot that "zero" should be the rightmost .. but the problem with union still persists :/

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?  Did you try inserting `printf`s to try identifying what is happening?

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?  What is the input?  What is the expected output?  How does the actual output differ from the expected output?

Comment: Sorry that was just my bad, it works fine except the union.. It's a test for a binary tree.

Comment: There's not a problem with "the union", you have a `printf` with a format string that says to print four things, but you only give it three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc warning:

```
main.c:72:31: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
        printf("%s  +-[%s,%d,%d]\n", sufix, root->name, root->value.t_int);
```

I think you wanted

```
printf("%s  +-[%s,%d,%d]\n", sufix, root->name, root->type, root->value.t_int);
```